# How to pass one or none variable arg in scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, variadic-functions, playframework-2.0

Having,

```
def test(args: Any*) = args.size
```

I'd like to call it with empty argument list depending on condition, but avoid if/else.

I've come out with this solution:

```
test(List("one").filter( _ => condition) : _*)
```

Is there better way than this?

For more context, I'm playing with Play 2.0 scala, and have this:

```
  user => Redirect(routes.Application.index).withSession("username" -> user._1).withCookies(
    List(Cookie("rememberme", Crypto.sign(user._1) + "-" + user._1)).filter(_ => user._3) : _*)
```

where `user._3` is rembemberme boolean.

I'd like not to call withSession or call it with empty argument list (not to instantiate Cookie) if rememberme is false, in scala manner.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think in this case embedding an `if`/`else` is the cleanest solution:

```
test((if (condition) Seq("one") else Seq.empty) : _*)
```

Comment: Thank you, I agree this is the cleanest, and I really did not want to avoid if/else, but avoid instantiating list, so I was just missing Seq.empty or Nil, so second answer is also useful :)

Comment: @alavez if your objective was to avoid instantiating a List, this is a big fail, because that's exactly what `Seq` does! You avoid it by assigning the part before withCookies to a `val t`, then calling `if (user._3) t.withCookies(...) else t.withCookies()`. Temporary variables are good!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Am I right thinking that using Nil will avoid instantiating List as well? And just for better understanding, is Seq.empty somehow better or worse than Nil?

Answer (score 3):

While Using list filter certainly works, it seems inappropriate here since you want either the entire list or an empty list and shouldn't need to iterate over the list members.

If you really want to avoid if/else, you could wrap the list in an `Option[List[Any]]` and use the Option's `filter` and `getOrElse` methods

```
test(Some(List("one")).filter{_ => condition}.getOrElse(Nil): _*)
```

You could also use `match`, which in this case is equivalent to if/else

```
test((condition match {case true => List("one"); case _ => Nil}) : _*)
```

Comment: So I've ended with:

    test((if (condition) Seq("one") else Nil) : _*)